# What is the bash equivalent of DOS's pause command?

Tags: bash, console

I need a pause on a shell script to show a warning before continuing.
For instance, on DOS it goes like this:

**doit.bat:**

```
[...]
echo 'Are you sure? Press Ctrl-C to abort, enter to continue.'
pause
[...]
```

How can I do this on bash?
For the moment a sleep command seems to do the trick and is simple enough but is not exactly the idea:

**doit.sh**

```
[...]
echo 'Are you sure? Press Ctrl-C to abort.'
sleep 3
[...]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Linux equivalent to DOS pause?](//stackoverflow.com/q/92802)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

something along the lines of

```
echo -n "prompt"  #'-n' means do not add \n to end of string
read              # No arg means dump next line of input
```

Comment: In Bash, this can be shortened to `read -p "prompt"`. More details on shell built-ins can be retrieved with the `help` command, e.g. `help read`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - That's without a trailing newline though.

Comment: @MattH Just like `echo -n` and `printf`. If you press Enter, you will get a newline.

Comment: that does not work for ubuntu 12.04 - read requires argumenst

Comment: @ses On 12.04.4 using `bash` there is no requirement that read have an argument. Using `sh` (which often invokes `bash` in `sh` compatible mode) `read` requires an argument. If you start your script with `#!/bin/sh` you will see the latter behavior

Answer (score 2):

`read -p "Press any key to continue or CTRL-C to abort"` works fine under 14.04 in my scripts. As @Lekensteyn stated in the comment above it seems this has been the case since 12.04.4. The 'help read' page states:

```
-p prompt   output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
            attempting to read
```

Answer (score 1):

The simples wait to stop the script is to call `kill -STOP $$` from the script:
After paused the script will continue its work after receiving -CONT signal.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0 stopping now"
kill -STOP $$
echo "$0 continues its work"
```

Comment: How does one send the `CONT` signal to the script?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite use of this is to set a default timeout, so that the script can also run unattended:

```
echo "Press any key to continue..."
read -n1 -t5 any_key
```

where:

- `-n1` tells the read to accept any single character
- `-t5` tells it to wait a maximum of 5 seconds for input

I work almost exclusively with Bash under CentOS, so I can't vouch for this working on other Linux variants, but since it's Bash, I would expect it to work.  I'd love to know for certain if it does! :)

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "press enter to continue"
read unusedVariable
echo "running these 3 lines in .sh file, this echo will never be seen, unless you have a really slow computer"
```

place these 3 lines in a .sh file and run it

Comment: -1 What is this supposed to do and why? Why would the output of the last `echo` command not show up and what does it have to do with the speed of the computer?