# What is "sh: 1: pause: not found"?

Tags: command-line, programming, c

I am learning C as first programming language. I have typed following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,s,d;

    printf("type the number which you want to add.\n\n");

    scanf("%d %d",&a,&s);
    d=a+s;
    printf("addition is %d\n\n\n",d);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I have typed the same source code in Code::blocks in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu using Code::blocks, but in Ubuntu when I run it, in the end it says

```
sh: 1: pause: not found
```

[image]

Comment: You shoud ask your question at stackoverflow.com

Comment: it is related to linux ,thats why i am asking this question here brother

Comment: Then you should ask it at unix.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: In my opinion, the question is on-topic here. The behaviour is not specific exclusively to Ubuntu, but it happens on Ubuntu too.

Comment: I would suggest OP does not execute any more code from a Windows example which has `system()` in it.  Very bad things could happen!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `system(...)` function in C takes a command as string (which is a char array in C) and passes it to the operating system's default command processor/shell to execute it.

On Windows, this would by done by `cmd.exe`, which has an internal command `pause` that prints something like "Press any key to continue..." and waits for a keyboard event before it quits.

However, Ubuntu luckily does not have `cmd.exe`, but uses `sh` here as its default shell (which is `dash` internally), which does not have a `pause` command. You can use something like this instead:

```
read -p 'Press Enter to continue...' var
```

See [What is the bash equivalent of DOS's pause command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/108258/367990) and [What is the Linux equivalent to DOS pause? (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92802/4464570) for more info, but note that C calls `sh` here and not `bash`.

So in your C code, the line could be replaced with:

```
system("read -p 'Press Enter to continue...' var");
```

This would make your program runnable only on Linux systems with `sh`-compatible shells though, it would no  longer work on Windows in this form.

However, please note that the use of `system("pause");` or similar (even platform-independent) alternatives is generally discouraged for reasons explained well in [system(“pause”); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/4464570)

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of the `system()` call is to *never* use it unless you have a *very* good reason. It launches a shell as a subprocess which a) is a somewhat expensive operation, and b) opens up the full shell command language (which is awful if you build the command line from input from the user).

Here, what you are trying to achieve with that, is printing a prompt, and waiting for a keypress. You already know how to print something, and reading isn't much harder. Either loop over `getchar()` until you see a newline (`\n`), or read a full line with `fgets()`.

However, since you used `scanf()` previously, the newline ending the user's input will still be in the input buffer. This is because the terminal will normally give the program only full lines, but `scanf("%d")` doesn't use the parts after the digits. `fgets()` also matches better with the terminal's behaviour here.

Comment: [fgets() also stops at an unconsumed leading newline](http://rextester.com/SWGBC83058), so that's no reason to prefer it to getchar(). But with getchar() it's not enough to check if the result is '\n': [it returns `EOF` if it can't read a character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). And if an appropriate buffer to pass to fgets() (not to be confused with `stdin`'s own stream buffer) is already handy, a fgets() call is simpler here (no need to check if it succeeded). But in favor of looping getchar() is how fgets() stops in mid-line if the buffer you give it is smaller than the input.

Answer (score 1):

As [Byte Commander♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) rightfully explained `pause` is a windows specific command and will not work on linux by default.
you can either choose between a windows or linux counter part at compile time by doing something like this:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32)
  define PAUSE "pause"
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
  define PAUSE "read -p 'Press Enter to continue...' var"
```

and in your code simply do :

```cpp
std::system(PAUSE);
```

or simply ussimply do :

```cpp
void pause()
{
   std::cout<<"Press any key to continue";
   std::getchar();
}
```

it works everywhere!